# Flyway Migration Conflict Handling

Tags: database-migration, flyway

Currently our company handles all database schema changes by manually creating,distributing, and running the necessary SQL scripts. Obviously this leads to issues as various machines get updated sporadically and sparsely.

I am researching more modern approaches for handling this, and Flyway is the leading candidate right now (Though we are still open to using Liquibase if a compelling argument can be made for it).

The normal flow is simple enough, and works as simply as advertised, but we don't know how to correctly address conflicting migration scripts. For example, 2 developers on different personal branches (A and B) adding the same column to a table in different migrations (MigrationA and MigrationB). The dev on branch B realizes that MigrationB wasn't necessary after he has already run it on his database. Unfortunately at this point, the damage is done and an entry has been written to the schema_version table in database B. Since Flyway does not support rollbacks, what is the appropriate response in a situation like this?

Historically we've avoided dropping/rebuilding our databases as much as possible, but is this mentality obsolete once you're using Flyway? Should we just be thorough in creating DeveloperData scripts so that we can drop our databases anytime one of these problems arises? Before I start telling colleagues that we need to start discarding our databases at the drop of the hat, I want to make sure I'm approaching this in the right way.

Thanks for any input- specific answers or more general explanations/examples of how people have successfully switched over to Flyway.

Comment: While I support the "clean slate" approach for dev/Q, word of warning from experience: don't forget to test migrations from non-clean states, and how the system reacts if it gets normal load. Devs tend to just create a few test entries and thus some errors slip under their radar.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

DEV databases can and should be treated as disposable, and Flyway supports that perfectly. It lets you recreate them deterministically in a wink. This both important for the scenario you describe above, and for many others such as setting up new test environments and on-boarding new developers.